# Qt openGL problems

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I download circles-in-a-cube-master.zip from [circles-in-a-cube-master.zip](http://codeload.github.com/peteristhegreat/circles-in-a-cube/zip/master). I build it successfully with Qt5.6. when I create a new prj and copy all the files from circles-in-a-cube-master except the .pro file(the contents are the same), the errors happen like this

```
debug/glwidget.o: In function `ZN8GLWidgetD2Ev':
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:123: undefined reference to `_imp__glDeleteLists@8'
debug/glwidget.o: In function `ZN8GLWidget12initializeGLEv':
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:173: undefined reference to `_imp__glLightfv@12'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:175: undefined reference to `_imp__glEnable@4'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:176: undefined reference to `_imp__glEnable@4'
Makefile.Debug:71: recipe for target 'debug\prj2.exe' failed
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:177: undefined reference to `_imp__glEnable@4'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:214: undefined reference to `_imp__glEnable@4'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:215: undefined reference to `_imp__glClearColor@16'
debug/glwidget.o: In function `ZN8GLWidget7paintGLEv':
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:220: undefined reference to `_imp__glClear@4'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:222: undefined reference to `_imp__glLoadIdentity@0'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:224: undefined reference to `_imp__glPushMatrix@0'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:225: undefined reference to `_imp__glTranslated@24'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:226: undefined reference to `_imp__glRotated@32'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:227: undefined reference to `_imp__glRotated@32'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:228: undefined reference to `_imp__glRotated@32'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:230: undefined reference to `_imp__glTranslated@24'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:233: undefined reference to `_imp__glRotated@32'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:240: undefined reference to `_imp__glPopMatrix@0'
debug/glwidget.o: In function `ZN8GLWidget8resizeGLEii':
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:254: undefined reference to `_imp__glViewport@16'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:257: undefined reference to `_imp__glMatrixMode@4'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:258: undefined reference to `_imp__glLoadIdentity@0'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:260: undefined reference to `_imp__glFrustum@48'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:261: undefined reference to `_imp__glMatrixMode@4'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:262: undefined reference to `_imp__glLoadIdentity@0'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:263: undefined reference to `_imp__glTranslated@24'
debug/glwidget.o: In function `ZN8GLWidget10makeSphereE8MySphere':
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:305: undefined reference to `_imp__glGenLists@4'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:306: undefined reference to `_imp__glNewList@8'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:307: undefined reference to `_imp__glMaterialfv@12'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:309: undefined reference to `_imp__glShadeModel@4'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:310: undefined reference to `gluNewQuadric@0'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:315: undefined reference to `_imp__glTranslated@24'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:316: undefined reference to `gluSphere@20'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:317: undefined reference to `_imp__glEndList@0'
debug/glwidget.o: In function `ZN8GLWidget10drawSphereE8MySphere':
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:324: undefined reference to `_imp__glPushMatrix@0'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:325: undefined reference to `_imp__glTranslated@24'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:326: undefined reference to `_imp__glCallList@4'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:327: undefined reference to `_imp__glPopMatrix@0'
debug/glwidget.o: In function `ZN8GLWidget12drawPendulumE8Pendulumd':
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:333: undefined reference to `_imp__glPushMatrix@0'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:334: undefined reference to `_imp__glTranslated@24'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:335: undefined reference to `_imp__glRotated@32'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:336: undefined reference to `_imp__glCallList@4'
E:\prjQt\openGL\prj2\prj2/glwidget.cpp:337: undefined reference to `_imp__glPopMatrix@0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug\prj2.exe] Error 1
```

What's the reason? All the files are the same.

Comment: I know what's the mean, please notice what I said.

Comment: You know what it means and you have a link that describes how to fix it. Do you still have problems? If yes, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37106726/edit) your question adding new details, or ask another question. That's [the rules](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the game.